# CSS help to create a box that I have overlay layers on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'd like to learn how to do with CSS.

I want a box:

I want the cards to be stacked directly on top of each over flat... Not vertically. that way I can use jQuery to tell the browser which card to show, and not have to reinject all the content.

I think GMAIL does something like this... You see an inbox, when you click a message it places the message on top of the inbox, keeping the inbox in the background.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to distinguish a visible div from the hidden ones, would be by using e.g. the selector :first-child. Here's an example where you hide one div by changing it's position within the DOM tree and the CSS only let's the first child be visible.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #container div { display: none; width: 400px; height: 250px }
    #container div:first-child { display: block; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function hide(div)
    {
      var container = document.getElementById("container"); /* Or use jQuery */
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div style="background-color: red" onclick="hide(this)">Click to hide</div>
  <div style="background-color: blue" onclick="hide(this)">Click to hide</div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow" onclick="hide(this)">Click to hide</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand your question, 
but to have a bunch of divs in the same spot but different depths, you should:

1. give those divs the **position attribute** (absolute or relative, depending on your needs) to place them in the same spot
2. use **z-index**, to give them different depths to show and hide them.
3. Use JQuery to change the z-index as needed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is to load all this content directly and then using Jquery to just show and hide stuff.

CSS:

```
.box {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
.box.hidden {display: none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"><!-- your default content --></div>
<div class="box hidden"><!-- your hidden content --></div>
<div class="box hidden"><!-- your hidden content --></div>
```

Then just use JQuery to show the `<div>` you want visible, and hide the others. It will behave as if they were all stacked on top of each other.